# Does using session state=StateServer and cookieless=true still store cookies on the user's computer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

In looking at persisting user information across a web session (.Net MVC), if we use a state server and set cookieless=true, is there still a cookie stored on the user's system, as it relates to the .Net authentication, etc.

We would also use the state server to store what would have been used in a session object.

I to realize that some cookies are good - ie, AntiXsrfToken and 
__RequestVerificationToken.  Apart from these, we are looking for a fully cookieless solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if we use a state server and set cookieless=true, is there still a cookie stored on the user's system?

This question is incomplete.

I can only give you the answer you're looking for: when using `cookieless=true`, ASP.NET will not use cookies on the client machine to store the session ID. That is **all** that this setting does in regard to cookies.

If you use user controls or application code that do use cookies, those are unaffected by that setting - such cookies will still be sent to the visitor's machine.