# Session doesn't work with Cookie in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, session-cookies, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart that store items in session. People can add items in cart but when they close the browser all data in session disappear. I set session state mode to `StateServer` and set `cookieless=false` but still after closing the browser all data disappear.

But when i set `cookieless=true` it works fine and my data will remain in session even after closing browser and restart that. The only problem now is that the session ID is shown in URL.

So i understand that my problem is cookie. My session ID is not saved in cookie or my application cant retrieve session ID from cookie.

Why cant i have a persistent cookie to retrieve my session data?

My web.config looks like this:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
             stateConnectionString="tcpip=MyServerIP:42424"
  cookieless="UseCookies" <!-- or false, i have tried both -->
  timeout="20"/>
```

By the way i am using ASP.net MVC5.

Thank you.

Comment: And you have your StateServer, you have the state service up and running, right?

Comment: @Hackerman yes i request from my hosting service and they have done it for me.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282619/does-using-session-state-stateserver-and-cookieless-true-still-store-cookies-on

Comment: @Hackerman i know if i set cookieless to true no cookie will be used, my problem is that with cookieless=true my session ID is displayed in url which is not good at all. i need to have a raw url with cookieless=true or a cookieless=false with persistant cookie.

Comment: Remember that MVC is stateless, because HTTP is...if there is no cookie to persist session, then the only way to share that info on the request between client and server is on the query string.